# Images/Buttons will not center

Tags: html, css

I have 2 text resize buttons/images on the bottom of my webpage, no matter what I try so far they refuse to center and keep going to the extreme left or right of the page.  Any idea's for getting them to center greatly appreciated.  Thanks

On the page -

```
<div id="sizecontroldiv" class="controlstyle">
    <div ID="resizetext">
        Resize Text <a href="#smaller"><img src="fontminus.gif"/></a><a href="#bigger"><img src="fontplus.gif"/></a>
</div>
```

Have tried various different methods of moving the images, all of which have worked in the past but for some reason just not working now.

Comment: You missing one closing `</div>` tag

Comment: oh yer... it is there on the site just forgot to copy it here

Answer (score 0):

To center:

`text-align:center`

This handles most cases, especially where the width is 100%; Sometimes you'll have to apply it to the parent container  of the object you want centered to make it happen.

If the width is less than the screen size,

`margin:auto`

It won't work for objects with `float`, as they'll go left or right.

If you are using `position:absolute`, this will not work. It will have to be implicitly directed to center by setting actual numbers or percentages.

## Update

Remember what I said about ***Sometimes you'll have to apply it to the parent container  of the object you want centered to make it happen.***

**CSS**

```
div { text-align:center; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
</div>
```

You'll find the image is centering just fine.
http://jsfiddle.net/Y7PtV/

Comment: using text-align:center at the moment and the images are on left side of the page... not less than screen width, not using float or position.

Comment: What are you applying `text-align:center` *to*?

Answer (score 0):

```
#resizetext img {display:block; margin:0 auto}
```